# Does "in" mean "for the purpose of" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This year's theme for World Environmental Health Day is "Prioritising environmental health for healthier communities **in** global recovery".

I'm not sure if "in" here means "for the aim or purpose of".

I found the following excerpt from the catalogue published for World Environmental Health Day:

> This pandemic has come to 'uncover' the inequalities, namely concerning existing healthcare in the world. There is therefore a need for a fast recovery and an unprecedented investment worldwide.

Comment: Probably not but it is hard to see exactly what it does mean.

Comment: I personally read "adjectival" ***in global recovery*** as modifying ***communities*** - which ***are in** [the state/process of] global recovery*. To me, it's analogous to *environmental health for healthier communities **in the 21st century***  (being in global recovery or C21 are ***current states***, not ***future goals***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, The following is written in the catalogue published about the theme: "This pandemic has come to “uncover” the inequalities, namely concerning existing
healthcare in the world. There is therefore a need for a fast recovery and an unprecedented investment worldwide."

Comment: The issue here is whether the syntactic structure as presented is *capable* of carrying that sense (which I'm inclined to think it *isn't*), rather than whether the writer of the text *intended* that sense (which is *possible*, but not really relevant).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, What do you mean by "the pasts of my stay"? Where did I mention it? What translation are you talking about?!

Comment: Sorry - I got mixed up with [What is the meaning of "recovering the pasts of my stay"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298579/what-is-the-meaning-of-recovering-the-pasts-of-my-stay), which I had open in another browser window Please ignore those irrelevant comments. (I've retracted my completely unwarranted closevote.)

Comment: in a situation of global recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would analyze this as "for" meaning "for the aim or purpose of".

"In" would mean, in this analysis, "during the duration of, in this time of"

Therefore "Prioritising environmental health for healthier communities in global recovery".

would mean

"Making environmental health a priority in order to produce healthier communities in this time of global recovery"

I'm not sure whether "global recovery" is when the healthier communities, or the prioritization occurs, but probably the first, because they are closer together in the sentence.