# What is the meaning of "recovering the pasts of my stay"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

Armand reads a letter written by Vincent:

> Dear Theo and Jo, it is really very beautiful here. I feel I see the
> North all the better for my trip to the South. I have settled down to
> some canvasses which I hope will go some way to **recovering the pasts
> of my stay.**

What is the meaning of "recovering the pasts of my stay"?

Comment: Is this about Vincent Van Gogh?

Comment: @Jack *all* of Zelina's questions so far have been about the same Vincent Van Gogh biopic.

Comment: @randomhead I only just now tumbled to that.

Comment: The sequence [*the pasts of my stay*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+pasts+of+my+stay%22) doesn't occur at all in Google Books. And when I search for it on the Internet I can only find it being queried on another "Help for non-Anglophones" website, and a contextless post on FaceBook. It's probably just a crap translation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the text is "one-off" as well as "non-standard", AND there's only one example - ***without a full context.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe he wants to remember images that he saw on his stay in the south, and will use the attempt to paint the images on canvasses to do that.